"Podfile not found" error after running Flutter
I have a Podfile in my flutter_directory >ios directory, along with a Podfile lock, but when I run flutter from the flutter_directory, it says "Error: Podfile missing."
So far I have:
removed the podfile and recreate using "flutter create"
also I have done this set of commands:
cd ios
rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock
pod deintegrate
pod init
pod install
cd ..
flutter run

still says "Error: Podfile missing."

I suppose you are opening your Flutter directory in Xcode. You have to open the iOS folder in XCode directly, not the entire Flutter directory.

So i’m not supposed to run flutter in my local terminal?

Run this in your project terminal,
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod setup

then run this,
cd ios
pod install
cd ..

Close the editor and reopen and then run your project. I hope this will solve the problem.

I've also tried this numerous times.
